# Does LINQ to SQL always use Transactions by default?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, transactions

I'm doing a code security analysis but i'm having some trouble to find out (in the documentation) if LINQ always use transactions when it makes the desired operation or if i have to specify some special attribute/parameter.

Does anyone know this?

Comment: This depends on which "LINQ". LINQ to XML, for instance, doesn't involve a database at all.

Comment: I discovered that [Entity Framework 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) will wrap the sql command in transactions if **Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()** is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ, in the general case, is merely giving some query provider information about the code that defines the LINQ query.  The query provider can do whatever it wants as its implementation.  It may use a transaction, it may not.  You could write your own query provider that wrapped every query in a transaction block if you wanted to, or you could write one that didn't.  You'd need to look through the documentation (or do some testing) for whatever specific query provider you're using (and potentially the specific query, as it may vary between queries) to see how that query provider translates the LINQ expressions into SQL.

Comment: maybe you could expand a little bit on the definition of "LINQ" and the difference  between it and say "LinqToSql"

Comment: @Bishoy I felt that I did explain the difference between the two.  What are you expecting to be included that wasn't?  An in-depth explanation of what LINQ is and how it interacts with query providers is going to get long fast, and would be going off on somewhat of a tangent.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to your question is NO.

With that said, you asked the wrong question.  LINQ is for querying data, and queries don't use transactions.  Your provider that you are using under LINQ may be able to change whether it ignores, skips, or waits for locked records while querying however, but that isn't part of LINQ.

Entity Frameworks, however, with a data provider that supports transactions will do transactions by default, which is probably what you meant to ask.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not an atomic transaction as you would see in a STORED PROCEDURE that begins with BEGIN TRANS.  You would have to enlist the System.Transactions namespace and wrap your using block in a transaction.